# Add custom field to all posts in specific category

Tags: posts, categories, custom-field

I want to bulk add a custom field (category) with value (photography) to all posts in a specific category (photography, with Category ID 5).

I have used the code below to bulk add a custom field to all posts, but how can I narrow this down to a specific category? Anyone?

This is the code I used for all posts:

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
SELECT wp_posts.ID, 'category', 'photography'
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WordPress functions to do this and just run it once, a fast example would be.

```
function wpse_85236_add_photo_field(){

global $post;
$photoquery = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1');

while ( $photoquery->have_posts() ) : $photoquery->the_post();

    if ( in_category( 'photography' )) {
    add_post_meta($post->ID, 'category', 'photography', true);
    }

endwhile;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_85236_add_photo_field' );
```

Remember to remove the function after it runs because you don't want it to run on every load.

Comment: Instead of running it through functions, which adds a risk of someone running the code twice by mistake, do it with a onetime php file... Also [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) comes highly recommended

Comment: Tried it in a php file so I can load it only once, but now it says Call to undefined function add_action() in line 14

Comment: Where are you putting this code, just put it in your theme functions.php

Comment: It's in the functions.php now and no error. I got like 900 posts in category Photography. Should it take some time to add the fields or should it be instant?

Comment: I don't think it worked. I also get a fatal error on pages with posts from Photography category. Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wpse_85236_add_photo_field(). Removed it from the functions.php and checked some posts, but no custom field.

Comment: This function works fine, cannot redeclare means you wrote it twice for some reason.

Comment: @Moshe Eshel , you can wrap the function in a `static` variable instead of a separate file but I did not want to confuse the OP. Also please come into chat if you want further discussion , these comments are getting to long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7460/discussion-between-aknl-and-wyck)

Comment: The solution works! I thought it didn't but that was duo time-outs. I tweaked the code and run the update per year and in some years even per month. This can be added in the wp_query like 'year=2012&monthnum=12&posts_per_page=-1'. Thanks Wyck for your help!

Comment: The timeouts are likely caused by not having enough ram and/or your php settings, your solution of breaking it into sections is a good one when you have those limitations +1 .