# add unique string as custom-field to every post

Tags: post-meta

I need to assign a unique identifier string *eg.* `524bbc5a3771d` to each and all posts (unique string for each post) in my site. So I tried to put together a code by picking up bits and pieces [from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85236/add-custom-field-to-all-posts-in-specific-category) and there and was finally able to generate a string. Here is the code.

```
function unique_post_id_generation($post){
  global $post;
  $generated_id = uniqid();
          $update_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=-1');
          while ( $update_query->have_posts() ) : $update_query->the_post();
    add_post_meta($post->ID, 'unique_post_identifier', $generated_id, true);
  endwhile;
}
add_action( 'init', 'unique_post_id_generation' );
```

The reason I used `uniqid()` instead of `wp_rand()` is that I found `uniqid()` generates alphanumeric value which I suppose is more diverse.

I have it echoed to my single.php as I needed, using: `<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'unique_post_identifier', true);?>`. It displays a nice randomn string eg. `524bbc5a3771d` but the issue is, it is displaying the same string in all posts. Here are a two more things I request you to keep in mind while suggesting a correction :

1. I hope that the generated correction will be
   **non-repeated-unique-strings**.
2. I need a unique string to be generated **only once for each post** so the code above is using add_post_meta so please provide me something like above which only have to run once, but again feel free to suggest any other way that is better and more scalable (not resource hungry).
3. I need the string to appear **on posts only**, nowhere else eg. attachment-pages etc.
4. The **string value should not change** on any post-updates.

This must be something very basic, since I am at a learning stage and I could be wrong in any of my approach. Let me know if I should try an entirely different solution with an sql query as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140198/wordpress-sql-adding-a-custom-field-to-all-posts).

Comment: Not sure why you need the identifier, so there might be a good reason to have it, but on the other hand every post, that means everything that counts as such in wp, is uniquely identified by the ID.

Comment: You are correct and I am aware of that. But I need to generate an extra identification code other than the post id, which will be utilized by many other functions. I wanted to leave the ID mostly untouched, although I use it for some important functions.

Comment: Just to clarify if you use your additional `unique identifier` just to identify the post, as replacement for the `post ID`, I wouldn't recommend it because it's a absolutely unnecessary step. The only reason I can imagine to do this is to obscure the `post ID` by using the `unique identifier` in those other functions you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simplier way to do what you want to:

```
function add_unique_post_identifier( $post_id ) {

$unique_post_identifier = get_post_meta($post_id, 'unique_post_identifier', true);

// do nothing if post type is not 'post' or identifier is already set
if ('post' != get_post_type( ( $post_id ) ) || !empty($unique_post_identifier) )
    return;

    $generated_id = uniqid();

    update_post_meta($post_id, 'unique_post_identifier', $generated_id);
}

// run when post is created or updated
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_unique_post_identifier' );
```

Comment: ,as soon as I tried the code site went blank, any idea why?

Comment: Where do you put it? It should be in `functions.php` in your theme directory.

Comment: Yes, there only

Comment: Do you have DEBUG on? Also I've updated the code. It was assigning the identifier for all types, not only 'post'.

Comment: Yes, I have the debug ON, how is this affected by debug ? is my only option to put debug OFF to make this work ?

Comment: No, keep it ON on production stage. I've just asked to check there are no PHP errors. This code works perfectly for me in both WP3.4 and WP3.6.1. Please make sure you've copied it thoroughly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10853/discussion-between-gurung-and-max-yudin)